# How to pass hibernate dialect in test using testContainers to match my container in a generic way

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, junit, testcontainers

I don't find any information on the reason I get the error below or a way to pass the dialect in a generic way.
I'm using spring boot version 2.2.4

I have the following test for my application with test containers library against MySQL.
I'm using an application context initializer especially for the test and I must set the JPA dialect otherwise I'm getting an error in the log, the test still passes but I'm trying to understand where the error is coming and why.
I'm searching for a way to pass the dialect in a generic way

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PetClinicApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {BootTestContainersSpockApplicationTests.Initializer.class})
public class BootTestContainersSpockApplicationTests {

@Autowired
private SpecialtyService specialtyService;


@ClassRule
public static MySQLContainer mySQLContainer = (MySQLContainer) new MySQLContainer("mysql:5.5")
        .withInitScript("db/schema.sql")
        .withDatabaseName("sampleapp")
        .withUsername("user")
        .withPassword("password");

@Test
public void testAgainstMySQL() {

    loadSpecialties();

    assertEquals(3L, specialtyService.findAll().size());

}

private void loadSpecialties() {
    Arrays.asList(new Specialty("radiology"),
            new Specialty("surgery"),
            new Specialty("dentistry")).forEach(specialty -> specialtyService.addSpecialty(specialty));
}



static class Initializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.datasource.url=" + mySQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                "spring.datasource.username=" + mySQLContainer.getUsername(),
                "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=" + mySQLContainer.getDriverClassName(),
                "spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
                "spring.datasource.password=" + mySQLContainer.getPassword()
        ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
}
}
```

the test works fine but when I mark this line

```
"spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
```

in a comment I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'SEQUENCES' in information_schema
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2439) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1365) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar:5.1.48]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:111) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268)
```

Comment: What does `DriverManager.getConnection(mySQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(), mySQLContainer.getUsername(), mySQLContainer.getPassword()).getMetadata().getDatabaseProductName()` return? This property is usually what Hibernate uses when trying to determine the dialect to use

Comment: it returns "MySQL"

Comment: Huh, that's weird, DB autodetection should work out of the box. I'm afraid the only workaround I can suggest for resolving the dialect to use at runtime would be to use the above property together with a `switch` statement. Alternatively, you might try debugging Hibernate's `StandardDialectResolver` to see why the wrong dialect is getting picked

Comment: thanks, by using the StandardDialectResolver  gives more control over the code